# Proving $nx - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i \binom{n}{i+1} (1-x)^{n-i-1} x^{i+1} = (1-(1-x)^n)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

I've been trying to prove the following equality
$$
nx - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i \binom{n}{i+1} (1-x)^{n-i-1} x^{i+1} = (1-(1-x)^n) \hspace{0.6cm} \forall x \in [0,1]
$$
What I've done so far, is to rewrite the right side of the equality using the binomial theorem, and have gotten to the following expression

$$
nx - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i \binom{n}{i+1} (1-x)^{n-i-1} x^{i+1} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \binom{n}{i}x^i(1-x)^{n-i}
$$
Now I can subtract the n'th sentence from the right and add it to the left side and reach to the following expression
$$
n(x - x^n) = \sum_{i=1}^n x^i (1-x)^{n-i-1}(i\binom{n}{i}x - i\binom{n}{i+1}(1-x))
$$
This is where I'm stuck. Induction doesn't seem to make it any easier, and I thought about dividing the both sides by $(1-x)$ or $x$, but I don't think that's gonna make it any easier either.

I would appreciate it if someone could give a hint on what I did wrong, or where to take it from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:
$$
i\binom{n}{i+1} = (i + 1 - 1)\binom{n}{i + 1} = n\binom{n-1}{i} - \binom{n}{i + 1}
$$
Now we can rewrite the original expression:
$$
nx - \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}(n \binom{n - 1}{i} - \binom{n}{i+1})(1-x)^{n-i-1}x^{i+1}
$$
$$
= nx - nx\sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i}(1-x)^{n-i-1}x^i  +\sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i + 1}(1-x)^{n-i-1}x^{i + 1}
$$
$$
=nx - nx(1- (1-x)^{n-1}) + \sum_{d = 2}^{n}\binom{n}{d}(1-x)^{n-d}x^{d}
$$

$$
=nx(1-x)^{n-1} +1 - nx(1-x)^{n-1}
-(1-x)^n = 1 - (1-x)^n \blacksquare$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Use: $i\binom{n}{i+1}=(i+1-1)\binom{n}{i+1}=n\binom{n-1}{i}-\binom{n}{i+1}$

Comment: Why not a complete answer then? ;)

Comment: It is immediate with this formula no? It takes time to write it lol

Comment: Yes. It can be proven using your identity

Comment: Alternatively you could change the answer to make it clear it is just a hint (it is what OP asked for anyway).